# Ansible, execute a task only on one host with condition

Tags: ansible

I am running into a problem in Ansible that I can't think how to properly solve.

In `group_vars/my_app` I have:

```
ldap:
      - { name: machine1.domain.com, machine: primary }
      - { name: machine2.domain.com, machine: secondary }
      - { name: machine3.domain.com, machine: tertiary }
      - { name: machine4.domain.com, machine: quaternary }
```

Then in the playbook the task I want to run:

```
- name: Patch only first machine
  replace:
    dest: "/opt/data1.ldif"
    regexp: "{{item.regexp}}"
    replace: "{{item.line}}"
  with_items:
    - { regexp: '__ANSIBLE_BIND_PASSWD__', line: "{{secrets[env][role].bpasswd}}" }
    - { regexp: '__ANSIBLE_ADMIN_PASSWD__', line: "{{secrets[env][role].apasswd}}" }
  when: ????
  no_log: True
```

My goal is to have the task run only on the primary machine as defined in the `group_vars/my_app` file. So I thought of this:

```
with_items:
  {{ ldap }}
when: "item.name == ansible_fqdn and item.machine == 'primary'"
```

but since I already have `with_items` in my task I am not sure if the best way is to use `with_nested` or if I should be thinking about this in a different way?

For reference my inventory file has:

```
[ldap]
machine1.domain.com
machine2.domain.com
machine3.domain.com
machine4.domain.com
```

and I run the playbook against these ldap hosts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the list *ldap* to a dictionary

```yaml
  ldap_dict: "{{ ldap|items2dict(key_name='machine',
                                 value_name='name') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  ldap_dict:
    primary: machine1.domain.com
    quaternary: machine4.domain.com
    secondary: machine2.domain.com
    tertiary: machine3.domain.com
```

Select the primary machine in the condition. For example,

```yaml
  - name:  Patch only primary
      debug:
        msg: "Patch {{ inventory_hostname }}"
      when: inventory_hostname == ldap_dict.primary
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [Patch only primary] *********************************************************************
skipping: [machine2.domain.com]
ok: [machine1.domain.com] => 
  msg: Patch machine1.domain.com
skipping: [machine3.domain.com]
skipping: [machine4.domain.com]
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: ldap

  vars:

    ldap:
      - {name: machine1.domain.com, machine: primary}
      - {name: machine2.domain.com, machine: secondary}
      - {name: machine3.domain.com, machine: tertiary}
      - {name: machine4.domain.com, machine: quaternary}

    ldap_dict: "{{ ldap|items2dict(key_name='machine',
                                   value_name='name') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: ldap_dict
      run_once: true

    - name:  Patch only primary
      debug:
        msg: "Patch {{ inventory_hostname }}"
      when: inventory_hostname == ldap_dict.primary
```

Comment: So I guess that because I am passing `hosts: ldap` I do not need to specify `with_items: " {{ ldap }}"`? The code will try the task against every machine in the host list?

Comment: Yes. This is the [concept](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/getting_started/basic_concepts.html#plays): *`"The playbook object maps managed nodes (hosts) to tasks."`*